# Image centered in a horizontal line

Tags: css

How can I place an image in a line with css, like in the image I have attached?
[Horizontal line with centered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PUmn.png)

Thank you :

I have tried this, but I am not sure about the html, because the line does not show up when I use just hr-tag, only the image.

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    background: url(//xxx/ornament01.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-size: 33px auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px auto 30px;
    height: 26px;
}

hr::before {
    margin-right: 24px;
    right: 50%;
}

hr::after, hr::before {
    background: #c0b4a5;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: edit your question to include the code

Answer (score 0):

use `style="vertical-align:middle"` to set line center to image .

```css
div{
margin:20px 0 0 0;
height:10px
}
img{
height:50px;
margin-top:0px;

width:25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg height="10" width="100">

  <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="200" y2="10" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  browser not supported..
</svg>
<img style="vertical-align:middle" src=https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg><svg height="10" width="100">

  <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="200" y2="10" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  browser not supported..
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a pseudo element with an `hr` tag or a `div` tag. `hr` has more more semantic value.

You do this by positioning the element relative, an making it's overflow visible. Then set it's color and border color.

Afterwards, create a pseudo element that is positioned absolute, with the top of the element at negative 1-half the current line height. This moves the half above the line and half of the element below the line. This works because the element is assumed to not have a height. After positioning the top of the element, we move the left side of the element to 50% the width of the line. Then, using `margin-left`, move the element back half of it's width. This positions the center of the pseudo element at exactly half the width of the line.

Finally, Set the background image of our pseudo element and fix the way the browser renders `hr` tags and apply a border to the `div` (if you choose to use the `div` method.)

```css
/* Position the parent relative. Set visibility of overflow and border colors. */
.fancy {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  border-color: gold;
  color: gold;
}

/* Add a pseudo element that contains our image. */
.fancy:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -0.5em;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px; 
  
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/nceI30v.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: contain;
  outline: 3px solid white;
}

/* If we choose to use a div, set the border color. */
div.fancy {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

/* If we choose to use an HR, set the border to be solid */
hr.fancy {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<hr class="fancy"/>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<div class="fancy"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the line thinner?

Comment: You can use the `border-width` property to change the line thinkness.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It's all CSS:

```css
hr.img-style {
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: medium double #333;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}
hr.img-style:after {
  content: url(https://media-touchdown.cursecdn.com/avatars/21/363/635430233878910345.png);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.7em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  background: white;
  height: 60px
}
```

```html
<hr class="img-style" />
```